# Keras word embeddings Glove: can't prepare the embedding matrix

Tags: python, nlp, keras, word-embedding

I'm trying to implement the Keras code (https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html) on word embeddings and I can't get it straight. I'm using Glove, embedding_index and I have a dataset with 5374 unique words stored in a dict word_index (len(word_index) = 5374. The embedding_matrix is set to zeros with a shape of (5374, 100) -- EMBEDDING DIM = 100

When I execute the code for the embedding_matrix it gives me

IndexError: index 5374 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5374

What am I doing wrong? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT6Vq.png)

Comment: I found this on the keras tutotial, I guess you might have skipped the +1, embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM))

Comment: oh, I just realized that the Github code and the tutorial code are not the same! thank you for pointing that out!